# keystonejs migrate users with password from another system

Tags: passwords, keystonejs, dbmigrate

I have existing system and want to migrate all data to keystonejs. Problem is 
- my system use phone as identity vs keystonejs using email
- in old database, I have password and salt fields. The encryption algorithm is SHA512. How do I convert it into Keystonejs password field?

Answer (score 0):

SHA512 is a *one-way* hashing algorithm so the original passwords are unavailable and you can't just import/convert them into a format Keystone will be able to use. Keystone uses bcrypt to encrypt the passwords according to [this documentation](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/fields/types/password).

You could technically rewrite Keystone to support the same hashing algorithm, but you're probably better off just having users set new passwords.